# How to keep track ng-repeat and change only that element

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I am building a post feature in my app. I am using ng repeat on posts and if length > 50 i will show "show more" button. And use will click on show more and will be able to see the text.

```
**Html**
    <div ng-repeat="post in post">
    <div class="post-block__content mb-2">
                  
         <p>{{post.caption | limitTo: captionLimit}}</p>
                  <span ng-if="post.caption.length > 50">
               <button ng-click="showMore(post.caption)">Show more</button> </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to implement showMore()such that it only show full text for that post only on which i click.
But in the above code i am maintaining 'captionLimit' which will make "show more" for every post. Is there any way i can keep track and change only the post on which i am clicking.

Comment: There is no ng-repeat in this code - even though that is what you are asking. Please post a minimal example, which runs for everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add additional property on post object to achieve this behavior. For example you could add captionLimit property on every post object and set it to 50 on initialization.

```
<div ng-repeat="post in posts">
  <div class="post-block__content mb-2">
    <p>{{post.caption | limitTo: post.captionLimit}}</p>
    <span ng-if="(post.caption.length > 50) && post.captionLimit==50">
      <button ng-click="post.captionLimit=9999">Show more</button> 
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```